# New Terminal not works when we use su root

Tags: linux-mint, root, gnome-terminal, su

When I use

```
su root
```

and then use

```
gnome-terminal
```

I get warning

```
** (gnome-terminal:2677): WARNING **: Failed to connect to the session manager: None of the authentication protocols specified are supported
```

and new terminal window does not opens.But when I use

```
su -
```

and then use

```
gnome-terminal
```

new window opens without any warning . Why is it so ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The environment setup when providing `-` is much more complete. From the man page:

```
The optional argument - may be used to provide an environment 
similar to what the user would expect had the user logged in directly.
```

In particular `SESSION_MANAGER` is missing if you do `su root`.

You can output the environments by using `env | sort > /var/tmp/XXX.env` with `XXX` being different for the `-` and `root` invocation, and then compare the output using diff. In my setup (Ubuntu 12.04) this results in about twice as many lines in the `su -` case (53 vs. 27).

Comment: So when do we use "su root" ? 
[ I mean If we can use "su -"  for everything ( + some extra benefits ) what is the use of having "su root" ]

Comment: That depends on what you want to achieve. `su -` takes longer to initialize, that might not be a problem in your use case. I personally tend to use `sudo -s -H` to get an interactive root shell. That is setup on my system so I can use my own password (instead of the root password).